# Python version mismatch during building a code

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to compile a code that works with Python 3.6. On my computer (Ubuntu 20.04), Python 2.7 and 3.8 comes pre-installed. Therefore, I manually installed python 3.6 using apt-get (I am not using any third party software e.g. Anaconda). I've also installed the development branch of 3.6 (something like libpython-dev).

However, when the code compiles, it needs to install certain packages (mpi4py, h5py etc) which should correspond/build with Python 3.6. However, the process detects Python version as 3.8. I have done the following in order to force the system to use 3.6 version:

1. In my bashrc file, I have created an alias for python (and python3) as python3.6

   alias python='python3.6'

   alias python3='python3.6'
2. The output of 'sudo update-alternatives --config python' is:

[image]

The output of commands python --version, python -V is Python 3.6.13. Therefore, I do not understand as to how to make the code works with 3.6. Please help!

Comment: you don't need to make system-wide changes, use venv instead. `python3.6 -m venv venv`  `source venv/bin/activate`, then use `python` and `pip` directly

Comment: @sify Is it a package?

Comment: [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) is a module added since python 3.3. In ubuntu you may need to execute `sudo apt install python3-venv` to install this module. Another option is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) directly, `venv` module is just a subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install these packages using :
`python3 -m pip install mpi4py(package_name)` or

```
python3.6 -m pip install package_name
```

Comment: This is what I tried when I manually installed the aforementioned packages. For some reason, it's throwing an error related either to MPI and I am trying to figure it out. My lack of knowledge about the code is another thing that is keeping me at toes to provide you more information.